# C Extracting string between tags from a html file

Tags: c, string, parsing

Hi I had recently learned File I/O from my programming class yesterday and there was this exercise where we need to extract strings from an html file and save it inside a struct .

I created a function to get the string "Hello World" but my problem is I can't seem to get the 3rd and 4th occurrence of Hello world. If anyone could explain to me why my code can't detect the 3rd and 4th occurrence.

Here is my code

```
void get_name (char *line, FILE * fPointer, struct Results items)
{
    char *p1;
    char *p2;
    char temp[100] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets (line, 268, fPointer) != NULL) {       //String//
        p1 = strstr (line, "<span class=\"title\">");
        if (p1 == NULL) {
            printf ("Error p1\n");
        } 
        else {
            printf ("word found\n");

            p2 = strstr (p1, "</span>");

            if (p2 == NULL) {
                printf ("Error  P2\n");
            } 
            else {
                strncpy (temp, p1 + strlen ("<span class=\"title\">"),
                        p2 - p1 - strlen ("<span class=\"title\">"));
                strncpy (items[i].item_name, temp,
                        sizeof (temp) / sizeof (temp[0]));
                printf ("Success!\n");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Text

```
<span class="title">                                        Hello world1                            </span> 

<span class="title">Hello world2</span>                                                                 

<span class="title">                Hello world3                                                                    
</span> 


<span class="title">                                                                                        
Hello world4                                                                                        
</span>
```

Comment: When your program does not work as you expect the right thing to do is to attempt to debug it yourself first. By using a debugger. Have you done that? What did you find?

Comment: It is very difficult to tell where the line breaks are from a screenshot of notepad contents. (which greatly effects your search for content when using `fgets`) Please post the actual text (with each line preceded by `4-spaces` so it is properly formatted). In some cases `"<span class=\"title\">"` does not even appear to be on the same line as `Hello World` (could be, just not possible to tell)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Hi I posted the actual text, it seems that my function can't detect the other "Hello world" because strstr can't find "</span>".

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be initializing your temp[100] with '\0' instead of '0'? Otherwise you'll have problems with successive use of temp as a string.

Comment: @MattAPiroglu - incorrect. `{0}` is perfectly fine (the universal initializer) as is `""` (empty string). The character `'\0'` is equivalent to `0`. Recall, with initialization, you only initialize the values expressly given, all others are initialized to `0`, by default.

Comment: @David, there're quotes around the 0. So it still won't work. To correct it, he should actually use memset(temp, '\0', 100)

Comment: @Noobplox23, Why not `if (strstr (line, "<span class=\"title\">") && (p1 = strstr (line, "Hello world")) && strstr (line, "</span>") { p2 = p1; while (isalnum (p2) || isspace (p2)) p2++; strncpy (temp, p1, p2 - p1); }` ?

Comment: @MattAPiroglu `memset(temp, 0, 100);` is entirely equivalent. Where do you find any difference between using `0` and `'\0'`. If you like the extra typing, its fine, but there is no difference otherwise. (e.g. the `nul-byte` is `0`) See [**ASCII Table**](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: @Noobplox23, Umm.... What did it?

Comment: @David, I didn't say they were different, and I know that you can use 0 instead of '\0', or better yet use (char)0 to show your intent. I believe the quote I put at my first comment has confused you. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to the advice given in the comments, it should be noted that using `strstr` to extract data from a HTML document is virging on insanity, [similar to using regex to extract HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

It's difficult to see what the goal of this exercise is, as I can't see what else has been covered within your class. However, given that structures, streams, strings and functions have been covered, perhaps you've also been exposed to using a *linker* to link to and use external libraries. Several options exist for *sanely* extracting data from a HTML document. These include:

- [libDOM](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/libdom/), [gumbo-parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) and other libraries which will parse HTML for you and allow you to conveniently locate the contents *without* reinventing the HTML-parsing wheel.
- [Many headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers), which will not only parse HTML for you but also fetch pages, submit forms, save cookies and execute Javascript without a GUI.

---

Not convinced to use the *saner* options? Well, okay, let's examine your code...

As you've demonstrated an understanding that `fgets` reads (at most) *one line per call* (i.e. your variable name, `line`), and the observation that your example (which should be *posted as text, not as an image*) contains the opening tag *on a line by itself*, it should be no surprise that your first call locates the first tag, *but further `fgets` calls are required to obtain the contents*. i.e.

```
printf ("word found\n");     // more fgets() is required between here
p2 = strstr (p1, "</span>"); // and here, because printf(line) shows us
                             // line only contains: "<span class=\"title\">\n"
```

This also explains why your second testcase passes (*everything is on the same line*) and your third and fourth testcases are failing (*not everything is in the one line*). To solve this problem, clearly you need to read *multiple* lines.

Comment: Thank you , I should try your suggestion! Sadly we are restricted to using strstr.

Comment: It's unfortunate that your professor is teaching you to reinvent the wheel and develop subtly broken solutions to problems; I'd be quite distrustful of such a professor. Nonetheless, do what you need to do to pass and move on happily knowing that you need to *question the motive and sanity of every exercise*. In this case, the motive seems to be teaching you about using one particular function. Are you also restricted to using `fgets`, or could you use `fread` instead? It'd probably be easier to use `fread`... or perhaps even `fscanf`... though all of these options are *virging on insanity*...

Comment: I wouldn't judge the professor without seeing the whole curriculum. And without learning some basics (even functions like strstr - probably taught after showing how it can be written), jumping into using the off the shelf libraries has a different focus.

Comment: @MattAPiroglu Fair enough. Don't judge the professor; judge the professor's *lessons*...

Comment: Agree 100% with the insanity comment, I took the question to be an assignment in manual parsing, if this if for the real-world, then yes, employ an html parsing library that has years of development rather than trying to reinvent the wheel yourself...

Comment: @Noobplox23 I suggest using `fread` here, perhaps after using `fseek` to seek to the end of the (*text*) file, and `ftell` to determine how large the file is... Then you could read the entirety of the file into memory and operate upon it as one large slab. An ideal method of parsing HTML would be to read from the file one byte at a time, moving down an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) as you go and *only saving the information you need*, thus reducing memory use... and *that's* what the external libraries will do.

Comment: @Seb Hi your suggestion of callng fgets again worked and I finished the exercise! Thank you very much and to the other people who posted!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes I also agree since I knew the existence of gumbo-parser but my professor probably wanted us to have a bad time haha.

Comment: Manual parsing is **always** a great assignment. Remember, you can always parse any string by simply assigning a pointer (or two) and working your way down the string (*"Walk the String"*) checking for the needed information as you go. Good luck.

Comment: @Noobplox23 If an answer solves your problem, there's a green "tick" you can use to indicate the solution to future visitors...